# Make a function that shows how many times a word occurs in a string/sentence

Tags: c, count

I need to write a function or a code that splits a string/sentence, shows every word, and also shows how many times a word occurs in a string/sentence. The code I have already splits the string/sentence in every word, but I still need to add how many times every word occurs.
The output has to be like this:

```
> Enter a sentence:
$ We like fries
> We: 1
> like: 1
> fries: 1
```

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
int main()
{
    char str1[100];
    char newString[10][10]; 
    int i,j,ctr;  
 
    printf("Enter a sentence:\n");
    fgets(str1, sizeof str1, stdin);    
 
    j=0; ctr=0;
    for(i=0;i<=(strlen(str1));i++)
    {
        
        if(str1[i]==' '||str1[i]=='\0')
        {
            newString[ctr][j]='\0';
            ctr++;
            j=0;    
        }
        else
        {
            newString[ctr][j]=str1[i];
            j++;
        }
    }
    for(i=0;i < ctr;i++)
        printf("%s\n",newString[i]);
    return 0;
}
```

Can someone explain to me how I do it, or show some code or a video.
Thank you.

Comment: OK you need that. Then, what is your *question*?

Comment: If someone can explain me how to do that, or maybe has a website or a video that explains it.

Comment: Use `strtok` with space delimiter, any problem?

Comment: But how do I make it so it counts every letter, because this code already splits the words, but doesn't count them.

Comment: Sorry, not `strtok` , you need to use `strcmp` for comparing one string with other, then  stores the string and occurrence in a array/structure with count.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do a 2D loop over newString and for every word compare it with other words in array and keep count of each word in an int array.
 this functions may help you:

```
char * strcpy ( char * destination, const char * source );
int strcmp ( const char * str1, const char * str2 );
```

also you can tokenize the sentence in a simpler way with this function:

```
char *strtok(char *str, const char *delim);
```

for more information about string function in C:

https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/